# Customising a Qt library class

Tags: c++, qt

Qt's [QTabBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html) has functionality to set the colour of text on each tab.

I'd like my application to be able to set the background colour of each tab. From what I can see, QTabBar isn't easily modifiable (e.g. by inheritance or changing a property) to do this.

This leaves me with the option of copying the QTabBar code wholesale into my (GPL) application, then modifying the class name (i.e. MyQTabBar), then adding my functionality. Is this the preferred method, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a better way :) You should be able to do what you want using stylesheets. [This article](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2007/06/22/styling-the-tab-widget/) covers some of this with a `QTabWidget` which contains a `QTabBar`.

Comment: Thank you for replying :) Are you sure I can set individual tab colours  with a style sheet? I assumed it would not be possible this way, since there are individual per tab methods, like QTabBar::setTabTextColor.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't catch that you wanted to color each tab differently. Using stylesheets, you would be limited to styling tabs based on the following pseudo states..  :only-one, :first, :last, :middle, :previous--selected, :next-selected, :selected, :top, :left, :right, :bottom

Comment: If you dig around the source code, you might find a way to customize the tab colors by subclassing QTabBar and overriding some virtual functions like paintEvent().